# How to get list of rooms joined by a given user in xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

I am developing the chat application using xmpp ejabberd. I want to develop an XMPP group chat similar to whats app. XMPP group chat setup is done on my  XMPP server. I am successfully creating the room & joining the room. But I want the rooms in which I have joined. I am using the following iq for fetching the list of groups from server

```
NSString* server = @"conference.test.com"; 
XMPPJID *serverJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:server];
XMPPIQ *iq = [XMPPIQ iqWithType:@"get" to:serverJID];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:[[APP_DELEGATE xmppStream] myJID].full];
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
[query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items"];
[iq addChild:query];
[[APP_DELEGATE xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
```

from the above code I am getting the list of groups from my server but I want the list of groups which I have joined or the groups from which I got the invitation.

Code for create & join the room is as follows

```
-(void) CreateRoom:(NSString *)roomJid {


static dispatch_once_t queueCreationGuard;
static dispatch_queue_t queue;
dispatch_once(&queueCreationGuard, ^{
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.something.myapp.backgroundQueue", 0);
});

XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:roomJid];
XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage jid:roomJID dispatchQueue:queue];
[xmppRoom activate:[self xmppStream]];
[xmppRoom addDelegate:self
        delegateQueue:queue];

NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
[history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:@"0"];

[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[self xmppStream].myJID.user
                        history:history
                       password:nil];
}


- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender
 {
    NSLog(@"Room Created");
 }
 - (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Room Joined");
}
```

If anyone have solution please answer the question. Thanks

Comment: how did you manage to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: (Swift 3.0)

```
    var muc = XMPPMUC(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    muc?.activate(stream) //Here stream is the XMPPStream
    muc?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    muc?.discoverRooms(forServiceNamed: "conference.localhost")
```

OR you can use this:

```
let xmlstring: String = String("<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/>")
let newQuery = try! DDXMLElement(xmlString: xmlstring)
let newIq = XMPPIQ(type: "get", to: XMPPJID(string:"conference.localhost"), elementID: stream.generateUUID(), child: newQuery)
stream.send(newIq)
```

Comment: I am using XMPPMUC to discover rooms but not getting any rooms.